# Yii Framework - yic migrate command doesn't work

Tags: php, yii, database-migration

I am trying to create a table using Yii db migration in safeUp() method. However, when I use the "./yiic migrate" command, it runs successfully but the table doesn't appear in the database. The following is code from the migration file:

```
<?php

class m130808_123826_test_table extends CDbMigration
{

    public function up()
{
}

public function down()
{
   echo "m130808_123826_test_table does not support migration down.\n";
   return false;
}

public function safeUp()
{
   $this->createTable('tbl_test', array(
   'test_field1' => 'int(10)',
   'test_field2' => 'string NOT NULL',
    ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');
}

public function safeDown()
{
   $this->dropTable('tbl_test');
}

}
```

I tried using a few suggestions from comments on similar issue like, providing 'up' or 'safeUp' parameter to the migrate command. I also checked the console.php file and it is configured to the right database. What else could be the reason for not creating the table in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide either the `up` or `safeUp` method. So remove the empty `up` method in your class:

```
<?php

class m130808_123826_test_table extends CDbMigration
{

public function down()
{
   echo "m130808_123826_test_table does not support migration down.\n";
   return false;
}

public function safeUp()
{
   $this->createTable('tbl_test', array(
   'test_field1' => 'int(10)',
   'test_field2' => 'string NOT NULL',
    ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');
}

public function safeDown()
{
   $this->dropTable('tbl_test');
}

}
```